# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CustomDetailView' with no arguments

Tags: ios, swift3

Getting error while I'm trying to do is simply create an instance of my custom class

```
class CustomDetailView: UIImageView {
  let packThumbImage = UIImageView()
  let packFrameImage = UIImageView()
  let packNameLabel = UILabel()

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
 }

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)   
  }
}
```

> var customPackView = CustomDetailView() // error here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding the following code in custom class, the issue is fixed

```
 convenience init() {
    self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var customPackView = CustomDetailView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

**Edit**: You have no empty initializer. Thus, you must use an initializer with a parameter.

Comment: So I have to give frame compulsory?

Comment: Yes, because you have no initializer without parameters.

Comment: Creating custom class without initializer will cause any bproblem?